# Get querystring and send to other file script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, query-string

How do I send my query string over to checkfolder.php?
I want to use my query string in the checkfolder.php, but I don't know how to get the querystring to have a value in checkfolder.

I need to echo out the query string in checkfolder.php.

Script:
I have also a $_GET['location'] that get the querystring.

```
// function get the querystring
function getUrlVars() {    
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}

// function that run checkfolder every 5 second.
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() { 
        // code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
        var txt = ''; 
        var first = getUrlVars()["location"];    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkfolder.php",    
            success: function(result) {
                if(parseInt(result) == "1") {
                    location.reload();
                } else {

                }

            }
        });
    }, 5000); 
});
```

I checkfoler.php I checkfolders for file changes.
In that file I need to write something like this:

```
if ($filesfound == false) {
    $location = $_GET['location'];
    $dir = "../img/uploads/".$location."/";
    if (!is_dir_empty($dir)) {
        $filesfound = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using POST request to `checkfolder.php`. You can pass data to the request and can get it from `checkfolder.php`. And i don't think `$_GET['location']` will work because you are not passing any GET parameters in your request

Comment: Okey, so how shall i do it? I have never done something with script before...

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, you need to pass value of `location` to `checkfolder.php`. Correct ?

Comment: Yes thats correctly my friend!

Comment: Maybe you should wait for the success/complete of each ajax call to schedule the next call by `setTimeout`. It could happen that you start a request, but another one has not completed yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameter to request like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkfolder.php",    
    data: {
        location: getUrlVars()["location"]
    },
    success: function(result) {
        if(parseInt(result) == "1") {
            location.reload();
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

and you can read this data in your PHP code. I am not a PHP expert but check out this ---> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Something like `$location = $_POST['location'];`. I see these are deprecated.

Comment: I cant get that one work. But if i write 'code'data:{location: "*ID of location*"},'code' it works. So its probably something with the getUrlVars()["location"] that dosent work.
If i alert getUrlVars()["location"] , it returns the right value.
So i probably need to write it in a diffrent way.

Comment: @JesperLundgren That's strange. `getUrlVars()["location"]` should return the value and assign it to `location` property.

Comment: And i don't think you have handled **spaces** in query string.